# Net5 wildcard package reference causes "NU1004: The packages lock file is inconsistent" error in in locked mode

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-5, dotnet-cli, dotnet-restore

I have created 2 projects in aspnet: 1 web project and one class library that references the first one:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.*" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <RestorePackagesWithLockFile>true</RestorePackagesWithLockFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\WebApplication\WebApplication.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

It is as simple as it gets, just vanilla new projects. Now if I run

```
dotnet restore --force-evaluate
dotnet restore --locked-mode
```

I get this error (after second command):

> C:\Source\Test\WebApplication1\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj :
> error NU1004: The project references webapplication whose dependencies
> has changed.The packages lock file is inconsistent with the project
> dependencies so restore can't be run in locked mode. Disable the
> RestoreLockedMode MSBuild property or pass an explicit
> --force-evaluate option to run restore to update the lock file. [C:\Source\Test\WebAppl ication1\WebApplication1.sln]

If the reference is not wildcard, it works properly. I don't quite understand why this error happens and if I am doing something wrong. From the looks of it I'd say this is a bug.

Comment: As you should've already noticed,  this looks related to https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8465